# Placing a sequence of images in zigzag order using PHP for loop

Tags: php, css, for-loop, foreach

I'm a beginner in PHP and I'm seeking your guidance to know the possibilities of placing a sequence of images in a zigzag order using PHP loop.

The number of images received may vary each time, so the img src code is placed in a `foreach` loop, I currently have them display one below the other but would like to know if there is an opportunity to place them in a zigzag manner as image attached

[image: Output I'm trying for]

```
$j=0; 
 foreach ($data['employee'] as $teammember) {
echo $data['team']['members'][$j]['TeamRank'] . "." . $data['team']['members'][$j]['name'] ;
echo "<img src='http://yyyyyyy/employeeimage'" . $j . "'.png' />";
$j = $j + 1;
}
```

I'm seeking your advice in placing the name and image in zigzag form.

[image]

Comment: `placing a sequence of images using php` that is impossible as all styling / arrangement is done by css not php. All php can do is generate alternate classes for the elements in the loop which will be styled by css to produce the zig-zag layout.

Comment: Thanks for the edit suggestion, however is there a way to bring this css code inside the php loop? like placing the images left and right alternatively

Comment: What do you mean by `css code inside the php loop`? Inline styles? What's wrong with using a external stylesheet?

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but I think you may need to go back and learn the difference between PHP, HTML, CSS & JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really just CSS. Put your loop or the data from the loop inside of an element that wraps it, and on that element, apply `display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: flex-start`, and use the `:nth-child()` selector to change every other flex child to `align-self: flex-end;`

In your loop, change this so that the text and image are wrapped in an element.

```
<div class="flex">
<?php
  $j=0; 
  foreach ($data['employee'] as $teammember) {
    echo '<div><p>' . $data['team']['members'][$j]['TeamRank'] . "." . $data['team']['members'][$j]['name'] . '</p>';
    echo "<img src='http://yyyyyyy/employeeimage'" . $j . "'.png' /></div>";
    $j = $j + 1;
  }
?>
</div>
```

And use this CSS.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  max-width: 50vw;
  margin: auto;
}

.flex > div:nth-child(odd) {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <!-- your php code would go here, and just output a list of images -->
  <div>
    <p>text</p>
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/lazyfonz2.png">
  </div>      
  <div>
    <p>text</p>
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/lazyfonz2.png">
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>text</p>
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/lazyfonz2.png">
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>text</p>
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/lazyfonz2.png">
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>text</p>
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/lazyfonz2.png">
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>text</p>
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/lazyfonz2.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great @Michael Coker, Thank you... This is exactly what I'm looking for, but when I try the same, for some strange reasons, Its being displayed one after the other.... aligned in center.... :( is it because I have some texts as well just before the image? like div -> foreach ->
 <sometext> br code and image src ->close loop -> close div

Comment: @user3563793 you're welcome. Hard to say, there's no text in your screenshot, but you're outputting text in your PHP. Can you post an HTML sample of the code that's generated from your PHP? And what do you want to happen to the text in this layout?

Comment: Please don't laugh... I was struggling with this for the past 3 days :)... you are a savior!

Comment: @user3563793 sweet! you bet, happy to help.