# How to place the div in the left to right and right to left sequence in the for loop?

Tags: html, css

As im trying the align the div in zig zag order in the for loop. 
So on the fifth div i need to wrap the div and start from right to left so on..

[image]

How to achieve this based on the width on the window?

Comment: I'm not sure about your requirement, but I think this can be done using CSS, by alternating b/w `float: right` and `float: left`. No need to use JavaScript

Comment: please paste your code

Comment: Is the number of elements per row fixed? or does it depend on the screen size?

Comment: Yes the number of elements per row fixed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44600377/placing-a-sequence-of-images-in-zigzag-order-using-php-for-loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Placing a sequence of images in zigzag order using PHP for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44600377/placing-a-sequence-of-images-in-zigzag-order-using-php-for-loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.row:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.row:nth-child(odd) {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.row:nth-child(even) {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.row>div {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div>11</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how to have 1,3,5 in first row and 2,4,6 in second row (that is odd div in first row and even div in second row)